# Hold me up / Pick me up

Tags: questions

My two-year-old kid recently started to speak English and it made me happy and worry in the same time because I could teach her wrong English.

I often ask her ''can I hold you?'' means that I want to cuddle her. 
She mimicked it last night said ''hold you? hold you?.
She meant that she wanted me to pick her up and swing her for night sleep.
I corrected her that ''hold me up''.

Am I wrong? 
Should she say ''pick me up'' ?

I'd appreciate any help.
Thank you:)

Comment: Thy both sound right; you should be in the clear.

Comment: As a native North American English speaker, "hold me up" sounds quite strange and not correct. However, @Sean says it sounds fine, which makes me wonder if it is a dialect thing.

Comment: You can *hold* a child while you are lying down or sitting. It means to support the child close to your body. To *pick a child up* means to lift the child from the floor or elsewhere, whether to hold the child or to place the child somewhere. *Hold me up* suggests lifting the child up and continuing to hold the child.

Comment: @TheSquareCow I am also a native English speaker and both phrases are used around very often (neighbors, other people). While pick me up may sound better, both should work fine.

Comment: @Sean on second though, "hold me up" does sound fine to me particularly if it is so the child can reach some object.

Comment: @Sean Thank you for the comment! Are you American too? Do your neithers use them interchangebly?

Comment: @TheSquareCow Thank you for the comment! Is the action the same but the purposes are different? Are ''pick me up'' and ''cuddle me'' the same?

Comment: @RonaldSole Thank you for the comment! Does ''hold me up'' sound right to you if the kid mean that she want me to lift her and hold her tight for awhile? Can I ask you where you are from?

Comment: @I'mALittleBus Yes, it does sound right. My life has been divided fairly evenly between Britain, South Africa and Portugal, excluding numerous travels elsewhere.

Comment: @I'mALittleBus I am American, yes they are interchangeable for the people around me

Comment: @I'mALittleBus They are pretty close, though "cuddle me" doesn't require the child to be lifted up.

Comment: Kids often struggle with you/me at first. Pick you up means literally picking up, hold me is fine, but not hold me up.

Answer (score 2):

There are some small differences in the phrases:

> "Pick me up" – lift me off the ground, for some reason.
>
> "Hold me up" – hold me with outstretched arms.
>
> "Hold me" – hold me close to you (hug me).

If your child is learning and speaking English as the local language from a young age, you should not worry. She will learn it very well from her friends and classmates – far better than someone learning it as a second language in later life.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! We don't live in a native english speaking country. My husband and my first languages are different, so that we speak English as our common language. Do kids say ''hold me up'' or pick me up'' to mothers? In japan, young age of children prefer to use only one word to refer what they want. In this case, they would say just ''Dakko''.